# Transmitter / Amplifier matching

Tags: amplifier, rf, schematics, impedance

I am trying to add an amplifier to a transceiver to increase the range but I am not sure how to add the reference schematics together (eg what components to remove, combine, etc).

The top schematic is for a RF switch design, so part of the circuit is to match to the 50ohms of the switch. By using that design with a 50ohms in-out amplifier I can reuse most of it without too much trouble. Basically the amplifier will go where the switch is on the schematic.

Here are the schematics with the corresponding values for each component and their description pulled from datasheets / reference designs.
Hopefully my unaesthetic illustration explains my problem clearly...
[image]

I suspect that **C3** from the second circuit is redundant with **C1** on the first and could be removed. Same for **C1** (2nd) and **C2** (1st). I think **C9** (1st) and **C7** (2nd) also serve the same purpose, but I'm not sure which value to keep. Finally I think **C3** and **C4** (1st) are equivalent to **C2** (2nd) and so I could remove **C2**.

I don't know anything about RF, so all these guesses are just that. I am really looking for confirmation.

This is what the circuit would look like :
[image]

Comment: What switch? Where is it on the circuit? What frequency?

Comment: The switch is the block in the center of the top schematic, I've removed RX circuit and enable paths to make it clearer. The frequency is 433MHz and component values are for that specific frequency.

Comment: Why don't you make (and add) a composite circuit then it's easier to see which components are likely to be redundant. Ideally you should keep C9 and short C7 for instance. Make it easier for others to help you.

Comment: I've added a composite circuit, keep in mind that C5 (1st) is actually an 18nH inductor, and R2 is a 56nH inductor.

Answer (score 0):

You are so far out of your depth it isn't even funny, rf power amplifier are NOT good beginner fodder.

Seriously, cut and splice 'design' does not usually end well when it is a UHF amplifier you are working on, you can pull it off if you copy entire 50 ohm blocks, (50R in, 50R out, with everything between those points copied), but lifting bits of matching never works out.

Why does all the stuff in red on the left of the '5324 even exist? 
You have a DC bias injection circuit there that makes no sense, a T network that does some matching to an unspecified impedance, this is then followed by a second matching network in black (C1, C3 and the matching line Lambda 1), seems overly complex to me.

On the output side you have a matching network (Lambda 2, C2, R2, C7 followed by an output LPF (But you don't know the LPF input side design impedance).

Also, I see no details of the transmission lines used for matching the amplifier.

The data sheet gives a set of S parameters that are a good starting point for this sort of thing (But only a starting point, the scattering parameters are small signal). Do a bit of reading, grab a Smith chart and you can probably have a reasonable first cut of something workable in an hour or so.